# Problem with ARGB_8888 and black background in some versions of android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am making a simple android application with NDK that draws a background (pixel by pixel) on an ARGB_8888 image.
I started from the sample [BitmapPlasma](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/bitmap-plasma).
All it's works, but now in some android new versions (like 10) instead of having a black starting image I have a fading from black at the top to a gray at the bottom (as shown in the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcW9o.jpg)).
Even if I go to set some colors at the bottom they remain light as if there was a fading but I don't know how remove it.
I tried to use setHasAlpha(false) but it doesn't change, while using RGB_565 type the problem does not exist (but the color is poor).
Some idea?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the problem. But in AndroidManifest.xml I change:
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
to
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
And the problem is solved.